# Gitlab CI/CD : Error cloning repository in pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

2FA is enabled in my account.
I have a simple `gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
stages:
  - build

build-job:      
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

I have installed the Gitlab runner locally in windows using following command and it is running. Also runner create temporary containers during CI/CD jobs.

```
docker run --rm -v C:\GitLab-Runner\config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "https://gitlab.example.com/" --token "xxxxxxxxx" --executor "docker" --docker-image alpine:latest --description "docker-runner"

docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v C:\GitLab-Runner\config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

It job give following erorr

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on docker-runner ecYGetzCE, system ID: r_liw1BfjncGQC
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:04
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:f8c20f8bbcb684055b4fea470fdd169c86e87786940b3262335b12ec3adef418 for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:51b67269f354137895d43f3b3d810bfacd3945438e94dc5ac55fdac340352f48 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-ecygetzce-project-5-concurrent-0 via 90e92b7f12d5...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/x/apxxx/xxxx/.git/
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab.example.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.example.com/xxx/xxxx.git/'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect, or your account has 2FA enabled, and you must use a personal access token instead of a password."

The authentication issue likely comes from the automatic source fetching done by GitLab Runner at the start of a job.

In GitLab CI/CD pipelines, the runner automatically tries to fetch the source code of the repository to which the pipeline belongs. That process is where the authentication error is occurring. Since the account has 2FA enabled, the runner is unable to use standard credentials to fetch the repository, and thus it fails.

To resolve this issue, you do not need to modify the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script section. Instead, you should focus on configuring the runner or the project settings in GitLab to use the PAT for this automatic source fetching process.

Do [generate/use a PAT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) first.

Make sure to define/use a token with [scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#view-all-authorized-applications) `read_repository` or `write_repository`

Update your runner configuration to use the generated PAT for authentication. You may need to modify the way the runner clones repositories to include the token. See "[Access Git over HTTPS with access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#access-git-over-https-with-access-token)"

Go to your GitLab project settings, CI/CD section, and add a new variable, such as `CI_JOB_TOKEN` or `GITLAB_API_TOKEN`, and set its value to your PAT. Make sure this variable is protected and, if necessary, masked.

The runner or the GitLab project needs to be configured to use this PAT for cloning the repository. That configuration is typically done in the project settings or the runner's environment, not in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Make sure the runner has access to the PAT through its environment. In some setups, you might need to tweak the runner's config file to include the PAT, especially if the runner is responsible for cloning the repository.

Comment: But I haven't added the command of cloning the repo. I just simply added the echo statement in script keyword in `gitlab-ci.yml`  file.

Comment: @PratikSharma OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.